# windows 10 monitoring external HDD

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, monitoring

I have a headless windows 10 machine (intel NUC) that I use for media.
I mounted 3 external HDD to high drive letters (m+) so that they always get the same drive letter and I set it to spin down after 30 minutes of inactivity (like this https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/21454-turn-off-hard-disk-after-idle-windows-10-a.html)

One of the drives keeps "disappearing". It is completely turned off and the drive letter is gone. I haven't figured out when exactly it is dismounting, but it happens sporadically every ~2 weeks. One time all 3 drives where gone...

Replugging the drive or restarting the machine fixes it.

2 Questions:

1) I think the drive might be failing? But when all 3 disappeared I thought something else might be wrong.

2) How can I get an alert (email) when a drive is dismounting? Should I install some monitoring software ? Most monitoring stuff I looked at gives support for up-time, bandwidth, cpu usage etc but no info if external drives are mounted. Or is is possible with Task Scheduler? I'm a total noob at using windows as a headless machine so any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A full blown monitoring solution would probably be overkill. A PowerShell script scheduled using the task scheduler should be sufficient. It would be along the lines of "Grab HDD List ([`Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/08/28/powertip-use-powershell-to-get-a-list-of-all-volumes/)) > Check whenever expected letters are present > E-Mail me if it's not the case".

Comment: Set the power options NOT to spin down the drives, and see if you are still getting the problem. It's also possible that the USB device is powering down (as separated from the HDD Device). Check there as well.

Comment: I forgot to mention that all external HDD have a separate power supply, should i still look at the USB device then? I will try with not spinning the disk down. But since it happens like only once every 2 weeks, it will take a while to report back.

Comment: @Seth I thought about something like that, but if i check it every ~15 mins. I will get spammed by myself that the drive letter is gone :-).

Comment: Well you could be smart about it. Examples would be to hold the failed state until the drives are available again. You could also choose a bigger interval depending on how much of an issue it is and how fast you're able to get to the device.